60's TV show about an alien investigating human behavior in a creepy house
I saw this as a child in the 1960's. A motorist watches a young man age and die within minutes. He enters a house to investigate. It is filled with an odd assortment of people who do not get along, with an exception of one beautiful woman with whom he falls in love. The motorist learns that the house is a psychology experiment conducted by an alien who has been observing the variety of human behavior among these subjects for decades: hate, jealousy, resentment, etc. 
The motorist declares his love for the young woman, but she refuses to allow him to remain captive in this emotional prison. While the motorist is watches she leaves the time-statis of the house and immediately ages and dies. She does this out of love so that the motorist will leave. He is heartbroken. 
The alien tells him that the experiment is complete: the alien has at last seen the human emotion that he was searching for: sacrificial love. The motorist leaves the house. The alien descends the staircase of the house; all the residents start aging and the show ends.

This is the Outer Limits episode 'The Guests'. I'd quote the recap, but you already described every detail perfectly. Still, our site demand it, so... ;) 

Wade Norton, a young drifter, finds an old man dying by the side of a remote country road. He picks up the man's pocketwatch, which contains a large photo of a young woman. Seeking help, he enters a mansion he sees atop the hill, whose inhabitants are surprisingly unhelpful but uncannily curious about the age of the man whom he found. With the exception of a soulful young woman whose image is in the watch, all seem mean-spirited and uninterested.
Trying to leave through the front door, Norton is forced backward and upstairs by a mysterious compulsion to discover that the house is the lair of an amorphous, gelatinous alien being who is keeping the group of desperate humans suspended in time until it can comprehend the disposition of humanity. It interrogates him then returns him to the group residing in the house where he is to learn the reason for their captivity.
The young woman, knowing the potential fate of the drifter, leads Norton to escape. However, she discloses to him that she cannot accompany him through the cemetery gate. The drifter chooses to remain with her in spite of the warnings. As she realizes he will be trapped among them for eternity, she departs through the gate herself and, having eschewed her protection from the passage of time, withers and turns to dust. The observing alien has found the factors missing in its equation: love and self-sacrifice. Releasing Norton, who has discovered in himself hope, it proceeds to deconstruct the house and destroy its tenants. The mansion returns momentarily to its true appearance, that of a rock shaped like an enormous brain, and then disappears.

It's available on Hulu here. Here's a clip of the woman aging:



